# Adding Sales Order to Netsuite using PHP toolkit amount error

Tags: php, netsuite

I'm getting an error when trying to add a sales order to netsuite via PHP toolkit

My code:

```
<?php

require_once '../PHPToolkit/NetSuiteService.php';

$service = new NetSuiteService();



$so->itemList = new SalesOrderItemList();
$item = new SalesOrderItem();
$so = new SalesOrder();

$entityRR = new RecordRef();
$entityRR->internalId = 10731;
$entityRR->recordType = "customer";
$so->entity = $entityRR ;
$so->currency->internalId = 1; 
$so->itemList = new SalesOrderItemList();
$soi = new SalesOrderItem();
$soi->item = new RecordRef();
$soi->item->internalId = 2551;
$soi->quantity = 1;

$pricelevelRR = new RecordRef();
$pricelevelRR->internalId = -1;
$pricelevelRR->recordType = "priceLevel";

$soi->price = $pricelevelRR;
$soi->rate = 55.3;

$so->itemList->item = $soi;

$so->subsidiary->internalId = 5; 
$so->location->internalId = 9;


    $shipAddress = "123 the street Hampton NY 11937 United States";
    $billAddress = "123 The street Hampton NY 11937 United States";
$so->shippingAddress1 = $shipAddress;
$so->billingAddress = $billAddress;


 $arr = get_defined_vars();
 print_r($arr["so"]);
$request = new AddRequest();
$request->record = $so;

$addResponse = $service->add($request);

if (!$addResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
echo "ADD ERROR";
exit();
} else {
echo "ADD SUCCESS, id " . $addResponse->writeResponse->baseRef->internalId;
}

?>
```

I get the add response of this

```
<platformCore:code>USER_ERROR</platformCore:code>
<platformCore:message>Could not calculate cost for the selected Realtime rate. Missing/Illegal 
 ShipTo/Address/StateProvinceCode</platformCore:message>
 </platformCore:statusDetail></platformCore:status></writeResponse>
 </addResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm not quite sure why it would not be able to calculate the cost and also say shipping address is missing

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are entering the shipping address as one whole text. Have you tried entering it per the address fields.  NetSuite has fields of each part of the address: address1, address2, city, state and zip code.

It might be looking that those fields which is why it is returning an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for those who are searching, this is an issue with pricing groups, to add a custom amount you need to match this with a pricing group in NetSuite.